# On incommensurate lattice superstructures and Neumann's principle

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry

I have a hard time figuring out how incommensurate lattice superstructures, i.e. with a periodicity not equal to an integer multiple or fraction of the lattice periodicity, such as incommensurate spin/charge density wave ground states can exist without violating Neumann's principle.

Neumann's principle states, as far as I understand, that if a crystal is invariant under a set of symmetry operations, then the physical observeables must also be invariant under the same set. I assume this requirement also to apply to the charge distribution of a charge density wave.

In the case of a incommensurate charge density wave ground state, my intution tells me that the original translational invariance of the underlying lattice is broken in the charge distribution in the CDW state, but I suspect my intuition is at fault.

I appreciate greatly any perspectives on this!